# Detectar boton atras de navegador para activar funcion ""valor.style.display="none" & "valor.style.display="flex""

Tags: javascript, html, div, display

acá con un pequeño problema, estoy desarrollando una web usando unicamente flexbox para que corra súper rápido y no tenga que recargar páginas, esto utilizando JS para ir cambiando las ventanas  con "valor.style.display="flex"".

El problema es que al momento de utilizarlo en el móvil los usuarios suelen utilizar el botón de "atrás" del navegador o del dispositivo para intentar regresar al menú anterior, pero como es de imaginarse los saca de la página.

Claro que todo  cuenta con sus respectivos controles para minimizarse, o al perder el focus.

Algo que se me ocurría era hacer un HTML raíz a manera de launcher para que cada vez que regresen vuelvan al inicio, pero claro que lo mejor sería que detectara los cambios que han habido y regrese de uno en uno.

En lo general con el código no hay ningún problema, funciona al 100, solo que me gustaría implementar eso ya que por esta clase de detalles la pagina se puede volver tediosa y hacer que los usuarios pierdan fácilmente el interés.

Algún comentario, sugerencia o si me compartieran los métodos para poder realizarse, agradecería mucho el apoyo.

(He estado leyendo sobre los elementos "window", pero aun desconozco bien como usarlos)

Answer (score 0):

Listo gente les comparto cómo lo hice:

Tuve que hacer que al presionar el botón de regreso regresara al inicio, el problema es que tengo que implementar todas las ventanas principales para que no se encimen

function ventanaRetroseso(){
window.location.hash=value_ver.style.display="flex",value_cerrar.style.display="none"
window.onhashchange=function(){
window.location.hash=value_ver.style.display="flex",value_cerra.style.display="none"
}

...